# How to pass this.props from parent to child component while using map() function without getting undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have two components: `<Content />` as the parent, and `<Curriculum />` as the child.

For the `<Content />` component, after getting state from Redux store, I mapped from state to props and passed these props into the map() function.

```
// import...

class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.englishEntrances.map((english, i) => {
          //Work
          console.log(`CONTENT ${i}`);
          console.log(this.props.curriculums);
          console.log(this.props.curriculums[i]);
          console.log(english);

          return (
            <Curriculum
              key={i}
              level={i + 1}
              titleColor={colorLevels[i].title}
              contentColor={colorLevels[i].content}

              //Bug here
              curriculum={this.props.curriculums[i]}
              englishEntrance={english}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//const mapStateToProps...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Content);
```

Inside the `map()` function, there are two array of object: `curriculums` and `englishEntrances`.

I tried to print `this.props.curriculums[i]` and `english`, the console will appear these values normally.

[image]

The problem is: When i tried passing both values in `return` statement, in the `<Curriculum />` component, only the `english` has the value, but `this.props.curriculum` is `undefined`.

Anyone know how to pass `this.props` value without getting `undefined`?

Comment: It should be defined. Are you sure the prop `curriculum ` is properly used in `<Curriculum />`?
Can you post the content of `<Curriculum />` ?

Comment: also in your code if `this.props.englishEntrances` has a greater length than `this.props.curriculums`,  this.props.curriculums[i] will end up being undefined for the remaining englishEntrances elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that the `render()` function in the life cycle of a React component can render right after initializing the constructor. In `<Curriculum />`  component, the value of `this.props.curriculum` will be `undefined` at this stage,

Therefore I have to handle event in that compoent before and after getting state from the store.